# How do I execute a function inside a namespace dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have the following dict:

```
In [6]: scope
Out[6]: {'bar': <function bar>, 'foo': <function foo>}
```

And `foo` and `bar` are:

```
def foo():
    return 5

def bar(x):
    return foo() + x
```

I want to run `bar(1)`, but it will need to find `foo()`.  Is there any way to run `bar()` in the `scope` namespace so it finds `foo()`?

I don't know precisely which function in `scope` `bar` will need, so I need a general method of running `bar` in the `scope` namespace.  I don't have the source code for and cannot modify either function to accept a dict.

It seems like functions have a `__closure__` attribute, but it's immutable.  There is also a `__globals__` attribute, but that just points to `globals()`.  I've seen some answers on SO that update `locals()` but I'd like to leave `locals()` untouched.

I tried an `eval` in `scope`, but get a `NameError` for `foo`:

```
In [12]: eval(scope['bar'](1), scope)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-f6305634f1da> in <module>()
----> 1 eval(scope['bar'](1), scope)

<string> in bar(x)

NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
```

Is there some simple way I'm missing?

Comment: is the function(s) in a module you can import?

Comment: It sounds kind of like you're re-inventing classes.  Can you tell us what you're actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `eval()` will work, however there are two problems with the way you tried to use it. For starters, its first argument, *expression*, should be a string. Secondly, since you're referencing `scope` in this expression *and* passing it to `eval()` as the *globals* namespace argument, you'll need to add it to itself.

This illustrates what I mean:

```
def foo():
    return 5

def bar(x):
    return foo() + x

scope = {'scope': {'bar': bar, 'foo':foo}}  # define self-referential scope
expression = "scope['bar'](42)"  # explicit reference to `scope`
print('eval({!r}, scope) returns {}'.format(expression, eval(expression, scope)))
```

However, in this specific case, it would be simpler to just let `eval()` directly look-up the value of `bar` in the `scope` dictionary namespace itself (instead of via `scope['scope']['bar']`):

```
scope = {'bar': bar, 'foo':foo}
expression = 'bar(42)'
print('eval({!r}, scope) returns {}'.format(expression, eval(expression, scope)))
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to create new functions with a shared globals dictionary:

```
from types import FunctionType

def scopify(**kwargs):
    scoped = dict()
    for name, value in kwargs.items():
        if isinstance(value, FunctionType):
            scoped[name] = FunctionType(value.__code__, scoped, name)
        else:
            scoped[name] = value
    return scoped

scope = scopify(
    foo = lambda: baz,
    bar = lambda x: foo() + x,
    baz = 5,
)

>>> scope['foo']
5
>>> scope['bar'](10)
15
>>> scope['baz'] = 100
>>> scope['bar'](10)
110
```

Comment: +1. martineau's answer was easier to implement in my case, but you pointed me to something I'd been looking for, which is how to "rebind" variables in a function in a different scope.  The docs are pretty thin on FunctionType.

Comment: @capitalistcuttle: You can execute `help(types.FunctionType)` to get a little more information about it (actually it's a class named `function`).